# No wifi-adapter found after booting with new kernel 5.19.0-32-generic

Tags: wireless, kernel, 22.04

Wifi worked fine until automatic update of Kernel to 5.19. After booting, wifi disappeared.

In ubuntu settings it says "No wifi adapter found".

I am not sure if this is a bug or a misconfiguration.

I am concerned because I don't even see the hardware:

```
$ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14d8]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14d8]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14da]
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14db]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14da]
00:02.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14db]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14da]
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14da]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14da]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14dd]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14dd]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 71)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd FCH SMBus Controller [1458:5001]
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd FCH LPC Bridge [1458:5001]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e0]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e1]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e2]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e3]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e4]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e5]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e6]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:14e7]
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5030] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5030]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f4] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:08.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:0c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
03:0d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f5] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
0a:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f7] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1142]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
0b:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43f6] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1062]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:164e] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
0c:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
0c:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP [1022:1649]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP [1022:1649]
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
0c:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15b6]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
0c:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15b7]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
0c:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    DeviceName: Realtek ALC1220
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1458:a194]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
0d:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:15b8]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
```

Here is some more info about my hardware:

```
$ sudo inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.19.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: X670 GAMING X AX v: -CF serial: N/A
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: X670 GAMING X AX v: x.x serial: N/A
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: F5f date: 12/29/2022
CPU:
  Info: 16-core model: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3
    rev: 2 cache: L1: 1024 KiB L2: 16 MiB L3: 64 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3046 high: 4500 min/max: 3000/5880 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 3000 2: 3000 3: 3000 4: 3000 5: 3000 6: 3000 7: 3000 8: 3000
    9: 3000 10: 4500 11: 3000 12: 3000 13: 3000 14: 3000 15: 3000 16: 3000
    17: 3000 18: 3000 19: 3000 20: 3000 21: 3000 22: 3000 23: 3000 24: 3000
    25: 3000 26: 3000 27: 3000 28: 3000 29: 3000 30: 3000 31: 3000 32: 3000
    bogomips: 287473
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD vendor: Gigabyte driver: amdgpu v: 5.18.13 bus-ID: 0c:00.0
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 driver: X: loaded: ati,vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL:
    renderer: GFX1036 (gfx1036 LLVM 15.0.3 DRM 3.49 5.19.0-32-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.0-devel direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 0c:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 0c:00.6
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-32-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Message: No device data found.
  IF-ID-1: bnep0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: MediaTek Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-7:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 295.47 GiB (15.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD BLACK SN850X 2000GB
    size: 1.82 TiB temp: 31.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 1.79 TiB used: 295.47 GiB (16.1%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 5.2 MiB (1.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 16.8 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 32.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 534 Uptime: 18h 28m Memory: 61.96 GiB used: 8.29 GiB (13.4%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 Packages: 2228 Shell: Sudo
  v: 1.9.9 inxi: 3.3.13
```

EDIT:

According to my manufacturer I have the following wireless communication module:

- AMD Wi-Fi 6E RZ616 (MT7922A22M)

  - WIFI a, b, g, n, ac, ax, supporting 2.4/5/6 GHz carrier frequency bands
  - BLUETOOTH 5.2
  - Support for 11ax 160MHz wireless standard and up to 2.4 Gbps data rate

Comment: To get it working; did you try rebooting & selecting the 5.15 kernel at grub during boot?  You can change kernel stacks to use the GA kernel stack (ie. *remaining on 5.15 for the life of the product*), even have the GA & HWE kernels both on your system (*some closed source kernel modules can prevent this; eg. some nvidia..*).   If its working on 5.15, switching to GA maybe a long term fix; though I'd be hesitant to remove HWE as I'd hope the 5.19 will get resolved in due course (*thus my stressing both stacks can co-exist*) and allows you to use your system as you look for better answers..

Comment: @guiverc good point. I booted with 5.15 successfully. But the issue persists. No wifi. I guess it could actually be a hardware failure - but very strange that it occured right after booting - or maybe it does not have to do with the kernel but with the configuration.

Comment: If it is a PCI device and you don't see it in `lspci`, then it is a hardware problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 It looks like it is in fact not a PCI device but integrated! I never checked whether the wifi was visible via `lspci` before it stopped working. It may never have been. According to my manufacturer, I have a "wireless communication module". I have added the information in the post above.

Comment: There are no "integrated" wireless devices. They are either PCI, or USB. That one is a PCI. Check if it is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 I checked in BIOS and could not find anything about disabled PCIs. Maybe I have overlooked something, there are many pages and subsections. I will call my manufacturer tomorrow and ask specifically about whether there is the option to disable wifi.

Comment: It is not disabled PCIs. It can be enable wireless device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @Pilot6 my manufacturer says that the wireless device cannot be disabled in BIOS. So given that the wireless device is not listed with `lspci` is this proof that the hardware is defect? (would be a strange coincidence in my opinion that it disappeared after booting with a new kernel and updates). Do you think it is worth it to install windows and see if windows detects the WIFI?

Comment: @waltinator not sure as your link is just about how to gather information, right? It is basically the same information I posted in this question.

Comment: It is either doesn't work, or is connected some unconventional way. It is not supported by Ubuntu kernel.